# Modify \closure spacing \moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I am trying to perform the following: Control the space before and after \closure

What I am looking for is specified in the following picture:
[image]

Which is produced using the following [MWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248626/add-place-to-the-date-in-moderncv-coverletter/248647?noredirect=1#comment592270_248647):

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}{%
    \recomputeletterlengths%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
        \raggedright
        \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
            \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\makebox[2\textwidth]{\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname\hfill\normalfont\textcolor{black}{\@date}}}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% 
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
            \collectionloop{phones}{%
                \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}%
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \raggedright%
        \addressfont%
        {@recipientname}\\%
        \@recipientaddress%
    \end{minipage} \\[2em]
    \raggedright%
    \@opening\\[1.5em]%
    \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}

\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
    \@closing\\[3cm]%Change to your liking
    {\bfseries \@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
        \\[3cm]%Change to your liking
        {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}
\makeatother


\firstname{XXXXXX} 
\familyname{XXXXXX} 
\title{CV}
\address{XXXXXX,12}{12345,XXXXXX}
\email{XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXX.XXX}

\begin{document}
    \recipient{XXXX}{XXXX\\XXXXXXXXXXXX\\1234 XXXXXX\\XXXXXX} 
    \date{\today} 
    \opening{blablabla,} 
    \closing{blablabla} 

    \enclosure[Im Anhang]{\begin{itemize}       \item Lebenslauf        \item Zeugnisse     \end{itemize}} % List of enclosed documents

    \makelettertitle 
    \blindtext[3]
    \makeletterclosing 
    \clearpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the definition of the style and recode it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}{%
    \recomputeletterlengths%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
        \raggedright
        \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
            \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\makebox[2\textwidth]{\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname\hfill\normalfont\textcolor{black}{\@date}}}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% 
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
                \collectionloop{phones}{%
                \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
                \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
                \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
                \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}%
            \end{minipage}\\[1em]
            \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
                \raggedright%
                \addressfont%
                {@recipientname}\\%
                \@recipientaddress%
            \end{minipage} \\[2em]
            \raggedright%
            \@opening\\[1.5em]%
            \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}

\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \@closing\\[1em]%Change to your liking
  {\bfseries \@firstname~\@lastname}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
      \\[1cm]%Change to your liking
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}
            \makeatother


            \firstname{XXXXXX} 
            \familyname{XXXXXX} 
            \title{CV}
            \address{XXXXXX,12}{12345,XXXXXX}
            \email{XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXX.XXX}

            \begin{document}
            \recipient{XXXX}{XXXX\\XXXXXXXXXXXX\\1234 XXXXXX\\XXXXXX} 
            \date{\today} 
            \opening{blablabla,} 
            \closing{blablabla} 
            \enclosure[Im Anhang]{CV} 

            \makelettertitle 
            \blindtext[3]
            \makeletterclosing 
            \clearpage
            \end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not doing it. If give 2cm , it will break the closing to the second page, although there is still enough space in the first page.

Comment: I just set both values to two centimeters, and it generates only one page. Your real document might behave different than you minimal working example. Does that work? If not, we need to fix that first, then we can look closer at the real document.

Comment: In my document, I have a list of the attached files. I just updated the MWE so you can get the page break.

Comment: Alright, please add `showframe` as an option to `geometry` to see where the textblock ends.  It just doesn't fit anymore. Using `\geometry{textheight=25cm}`eveerything will fit again. You can play around with the margins.

Comment: The `showframe` is a very interesting option . Thanks! 
Where exactly should I use `\geometry{textheight=25cm}`  If i want it to affect only the first page (i.e only the cover letter)?

Comment: Oh, that is a bit more complex. You can use `\newgeometry` to change the layout mid-document, but i think it will be easier splitting the document in two parts and inlcude one part in the other using package `pdfpages`.