# How to add skype & photo entries using moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I'm trying to generate a CV using this code. But, I wasn't able to find how to add a skype entry to this code and another for photo one.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,francais]{moderncv}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\firstname{XX}
\familyname{XX}
\title{XX}              
\address{XX}{XX}    
\email{XX@XX.X}                      
\homepage{}
\mobile{XX} 
\extrainfo{XX}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\personaltitle{
  \def\phonesdetails{}
  \collectionloop{phones}{
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
 \par\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
     {\LARGE\textbf{\@lastname\ \@firstname}} \\
     \@addressstreet \\
     \@addresscity  \\
     \@extrainfo \\
     \mobilephonesymbol:\ \collection@phones@item  \\
     \emailsymbol:\ \emaillink{\@email} \\
     \githubsocialsymbol:\ \httplink{\@homepage} \\
 \end{tabular}\par%\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par%
}
\begin{document}

\personaltitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

How to deal with? Any brilliant idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest version of the `FontAwesome` font because Skype symbol is new. Then, in the preamble add the two lines

```
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\providecommand\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
```

and compile. The second line is required because `\faSkype` doesn't simply work out of the box.

With `\faSkype\ John.Aims`, for example, you can expect some thing like this:

[image]

Without a MWE, I cannot explain any further.

**Edit:** With a MWE added.

I updated my solution for your MWE, but I recommend starting your document from scratch without that ugly block `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` from another question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252132/modify-closure-spacing-moderncv) and add only the commands you need. For adding the photo, add the line `\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}` to your personal information. Replace the `picture` with your actual photo. If you don't like the `classic` style you can use `casual` or `oldstyle`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,francais]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\usepackage{babel,fontawesome}
\providecommand\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\firstname{XX}
\familyname{XX}
\title{XX}              
\address{XX}{XX}    
\email{XX@XX.X}                      
\homepage{}
\mobile{XX} 
\extrainfo{\faSkype\ John.Aims}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried to put that code into the posted snippet one, please?

Comment: @JohnAims : Please provide a compilable code starting with `\documentclass{}  ...` and ending with `\end{document}`, and people here can help you.

Comment: I've just posted a MWE ;)

Comment: What about the inclusion of a profile photo?

Comment: @JohnAims What's wrong with the photo? You simply need to put in the same directory where you created your `main.tex` document, assuming that file is where you create your CV.

Comment: I've got this: `! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
!
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
!
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.`

Comment: @JohnAims Yes, that is because of using `fontspec` which was very important to have access to TrueType fonts in your system and fontawesome. To compile correctly, use for example `lualatex cv.tex` as I did.

Comment: I need pdflatex :/ Is there any alternative for `fontspec` ?

Comment: @JohnAims If you need fontawesome, you won't be able to use pdflatex unfortunately, but why do you stick to pdflatex? AFAIK, lualatex can do almost any thing pdflatex can plus truetype fonts and some other things

Comment: I used `\faSkype\ ` directly and it worked like a charm.